# Wont add dependencies because of missing service fabric packages

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-service-fabric

Starting a new empty .NET Core 2 class library i try to add any dependency with nuget i get this error

> Error      The local source 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\packages' doesn't exist.

But service fabric should have nothing to do with this solution . Also the solution builds succesfully

Comment: are you building a service fabric related class library?

Comment: No. Not at all. Net core console application.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I faced the same error.

There was service fabric installed but I decided to delete it. Then after that, this error started to appear.

All you have to do is create an empty packages folder

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\packages
```

Answer (score 21):

In VS2019 remove Service Fabric's package source by going to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager\Package Sources
```

and unchecking the **Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK** option.

Comment: This should be the answer. This is the correct way to handle it and not a work around.

Comment: In some cases the package is installed globally, which require you to run VS as Administrator to change the setting or remove the Service Fabric package.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in VS 2019 despite uninstalling what I thought was all of Service Fabric long ago, and only using it in 2017.  Adding the missing folder resolved the problem, although I don't know the root cause.

Answer (score -2):

Solved it by uninstalling visual studio 2017 and installing 2019. I suspect its something that went wrong when i installed Service Fabric SDK (which i was not using for this project). With 2019 it works even when having SF installed.