# Unable to add NuGet packages

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have started a new sample .NET Core 3.1 project to use Gremlin.NET to connect to CosmosDB Graph API and can't seem to get the Gremlin.NET package installed. The problem is when I run `dotnet add package Gremlin.NET`, I get the following output:

```
  Writing C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp343B.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Gremlin.NET' into project 'C:\opt\Source\...\gremlin-spike\gremlin-spike.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for C:\opt\Source\...\gremlin-spike\gremlin-spike.csproj...
error: The local source 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\packages\' doesn't exist.
```

The problem is the last line where it is attempting save package into the Service Fabric packages directory, but I no longer have Service Fabric installed and the directory no longer exists. I have looked at all the `nuget.config` files I can find and none of them have a package source pointing to that directory. How do I *reset* .NET Core to use the default packages folder location instead of this value?

Comment: Refer this [Wont add dependencies because of missing service fabric packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245714/wont-add-dependencies-because-of-missing-service-fabric-packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty folder here:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\packages

Comment: Hahaha, obviously that will get me moving right now but I would rather find the source of this issue because it might be causing other issues as well.

Comment: @kyko, glad I could help. have a nice day.